# Receiving nested Neo4j resutls with Golang

Tags: neo4j, neoism, neo4j-plugin

I have a problem with transferring a response from Neo4j to Golang using neoism.

The Neo4j response has nested structure and is assembled with Neo4j plugin in the [following way](https://gist.github.com/mahinko/497326674dbbc0e4e474f1882b39c02c).

I can see that the response is correct in the Neo4j panel. The problem appears when I'm trying to get the response with [Golang](https://gist.github.com/mahinko/7c471d02dfd1086ebb132707b3fb3e26).

The following error is received: "*Unsupported property type: class pkgName.Dev$NestedReport*"

The problem isn't reproduced in case if only one top-level element is present in the results.

What is the best way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the wrong testing.